# Kolbe's electrolysis of acetylenedicarboxylic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds

I have been wondering what this reaction would lead to?
The ethyne diradical can't dimerize because triple bonded cyclic structures don't form until 8 carbons. And even if it polymerizes I find no way to end it's chain. This could probably lead to the [carbyne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_acetylenic_carbon).

Is there any literature on this out there?

Comment: I'm not completely up on Kolbe mechanism, but why do you think a diradical would form?  Presumably it could only form stepwise, with a mono-radical forming first.  This would have to last long enough, not reacting with anything else, and be as prone to homolysis as the original non-radical carboxylate ion, to form.  Not clear to me that it could.  What is the Kolbe product of even a "regular" dicarboxylate like succinic acid?

Comment: I think you are confused about the 8 carbon ring. While (E)-cyclooctene is stable. cyclodecyne is the smallest isolable cycloalkyne. In your query I believe your only source of carbon is the "diradical of acetylene". The polymerization would give a linear polyacetylene that would have to be extremely long to bite its own tail, if it could wind it. As to termination, the C-H bond dissociation energy of acetylene is 133 kcal/mol. The radical is very reactive and can abstract hydrogen from  the walls of the vessel.